# What does \ mean in bash and find?

Tags: bash, find, syntax

I know that `\` is an escape character, but when I write `\` in bash, I have something like this:

```
System-Product-Name:~$ \
>
```

So bash waits for some instructions?
When I use

```
System-Product-Name:~$ \
> ls
```

It is working.
But when I use

```
System-Product-Name:~$ cd Wideo \
> ls
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

So backslash is working like a pipe `|` ? I don't think so.

And when I use this command:

```
find . -name "FILENAME"  -exec rm {} \;
```

Why do I need to terminate it? I thought that the command `find` finds proper files and in `exec` removes them from the path where it found them. Without that, I have information that `-exec` doesn't have any arguments, I don't get it. Why I can't just use

```
find . -name "FILENAME"  -exec rm {}
```

?

I have only that information about exec in man find:

> exec   Show diagnostic information relating to -exec,  -execdir, -ok and -okdir

So why do I need to terminate when I use exec? For example when I use

```
find . -name "FILENAME"
```

I don't need to terminate.

Comment: "What does `\ ` mean in bash and find?" – Even in your example with `find` the backslash means much to the shell but *nothing* to `find`, as `find` does not get it. See [what happens when `find` does get it](https://superuser.com/q/1762511/432690).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should distinguish the `\` at the end of a line which means "this isn't the end of the line, the line continues on the next one" (then your `cd` command has 2 arguments, too much), and the `\` inside a line which prevents the next character from having a special meaning.

Then, `\;` in your example means give `find` a literal `;` as an argument. Without `\`, the `;` will have its special meaning to the shell, and will work as a separator between the `find` command and a next one.

The `;` argument is needed when you use `find` with an `-exec` option so that `find` knows where the command given with `-exec` ends. Another alternative is the two arguments `{}` and `+`. You should read the `find(1)` manual for more information.

Comment: Arguably, the backslash at the end of the line has exactly the same meaning as the backslash inside the line, they both remove the special meaning of the next character (the newline character, and the `;` character, respectively). The two cases need not be separated or distinguished from each other.

Comment: `/` is seldom used on interactive session. It is mostly usefull in bash script when using a command with many parameter, command can be split in 2 or more lines.

Comment: If you type `echo a\<newline>b` the newline is suppressed not given to echo unchanged. Unlike a \ before an other char.  I think it would be better to explain 2 cases instead of one.

Comment: @Kusalananda, compare backslash-newline vs. quote-newline-quote and backslash-semicolon vs. quote-semicolon-quote (with either double or single quotes here)

Comment: @ilkkachu That would have a different effect, though. The backslash removes the special meaning of the subsequent character. In the given code, both the newline and the semi-colon act as command terminators but will not act as command terminators when preceded by a backslash.

Comment: `\<newline>` is equivalent to nothing at all. `\<an_other_char>` is equivalent to the other char uninterpreted by the shell. Then the meaning of `\ ` is different. Try `echo a\<newline>b`, you will see `echo` to print `ab` not `a<newline>b`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, backslash removes the special meaning of the following character, like quotes do. But if the following character is a newline, _it removes the whole character_, instead of leaving it as a literal, like quotes do, and like the backslash does to other special characters. E.g. `echo :<backslash><newline>:<newline>` prints back-to-back colons, while `echo :"<newline>":<newline>` prints two colons with a newline in between.

Comment: @ilkkachu Then we agree. The backslash removes the special meaning of the subsequent character. Note that I never said anything about whether the actual character was removed or not, which it obviously is in the case of the newline, only that the special meaning, the "let's end the command here"-effect, was removed.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, they nor I don't agree with you on that, backslash in front of newline removes that newline while for any other character, it's a quoting operator `\;` is like `';'` or `";"`, `\<newline>` is not like `'<newline>'`. So saying it has the very same meaning is misleading it's like saying backslash removes its special meaning to `n` when it changes `\n` to newline in fish or es. Also note that `\<newline>` is also removed within double quotes or here documents with unquoted delimiter (inside which newline doesn't have a special meaning) or arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh dear. Where do I say anything about removing characters?! I really only talk about removing the command-terminating effect. You can't say that a backslash is removing a newline in a source file. It does however remove the command-terminating effect of that newline. Yes, when the script is run, the newline disappears, obviously. In both cases in the given code, the backslash means "this is not the end of the command". Without the backslash, both the newline and the semicolon would have been command terminators.  It is therefore not necessary to distinguish between two cases

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My comment here is about the distinction that the answer is doing between a semi colon and newline. They are both command terminators. The backslash removes the command terminating effect. There is no need to distinguish two cases. End.  Yes, the backslash remove the newline but quotes the semicolon. I'm not really commenting on that.

Comment: @Kusalananda, right, you didn't mention removing characters. But you did say _"[it] has exactly the same meaning"_ and _"The two cases need not be separated or distinguished from each other."_ while generally one uses a backslash or quotes to pass a character literally as an argument (or so), like with `find -exec ... \;` here. Or if e.g. setting `IFS` to just the newline, with `IFS='<newline>'`. And in that use, the `\<newline>` combination in particular is different from the cases with quotes or escapes, exactly because it doesn't work for that use but does something different.

Comment: Now, if you then say "Yes, the backslash remove the newline but quotes the semicolon.", then doesn't that kinda contradict the "has exactly the same meaning" part? IMO, it's worth noting the difference, because it might not be obvious to a random user that in this particular case the using the backslash to escape something does not work the same as using quotes. @FrédéricLoyer's answer also says "`\;` in your example means give `find` a `;` argument.", and that's not exactly the same as the newline case, because there, no argument with the newline is passed to the command.

Comment: @ilkkachu I believe we're all aware of what we are discussing and how things work. It is obvious that my attempt at showing that the answer could possibly be made simpler did not find enough traction to be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The \ character used in this way is usually referred to as "escapeing" the next character so that bash will remove any special meaning for the character that follows and instead treat it as a literal character rather than process it as part of the bash command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871336/1663987 for a reference to the bash manual and additional info.

So for

```
find . -name "FILENAME"  -exec rm {} \;
```

it tells bash to insert a literal semicolon into the find command arguments rather than process that as a separator between bash commands (ala `echo hello; echo world`)

For

```
ls some\ file
```

it tells bash to treat the space as part of the filename rather than as the character that separates arguments to ls. Thus, it will show `ls` output for the single file named "some file" (and not two different files named "some" and "file" as it would if just `ls some file` was used).

For

```
cd Wideo \
> ls
```

it telling bash to continue looking for arguments rather than processing the newline as the end of a command, so that the command ends up being processed like `cd Wideo ls`. This effect is usually referred to as line continuation.

Comment: But in the case of newline, it also removes the character. If you do `cd Wideo\<newline>ls` it will be equivalent to `cd Wideols`. That's why you have to put a space before the backslash.

Comment: @Barmar Completely agree, but it is probably better for general understanding to note that technically in the case of \ at the end of the line, it is telling bash to remove the special meaning of the newline that follows (i.e. end of a command; process this input), with the effective result that it allows you to continue the command on the next line. That way, input like `ls Wideo\ \<newline>ls<newline>` makes it clear why the command is interpreted as trying to `ls` the file `Wideo ls` (with a space part of the name) since both the space and newline no longer have their bash special meaning.

Comment: The point is that all the other uses of backslash make the next character literal. Backslash-newline doesn't result in a literal newline, it results in nothing.

Comment: I generally agree, except that is not true within quotes and therefore is not an absolute statement. `echo "\d\z\k"` outputs `\d\z\k` because those characters have no special meaning to bash inside quoted strings, unlike `\f` (formfeed), `\n` (newline), and a few others.

Comment: `\f` and `\n` have no special meaning in a quoted string, either. But yes, backslash behaves differently inside quotes, it's literal unless it's before something that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

"In bash", it's escaping your newline. In find, it's escaping `;`.

Normally, when you type `Enter`, the shell will read that as the end of the command. If you put `\Enter` it will interpret that as literally a new line.

The second part of the puzzle here is to realize that commands and arguments can contain newlines. There's no rule saying they can't. Most people just avoid using them because they are inconvenient.

However, the following is a valid filename and a valid argument to `ls`, `cd` and others:

```
foo
bar
```

You can't just type

```
cd foo
bar
```

in your shell, because it will try to `cd foo` and then run `bar`. But you should be able to do

```
cd 'foo
bar'
```

With `find`, you have a syntax like `find -exec some_command`. Since `some_command` can contain spaces, `find` will look for `;` to figure out where the command ends. If you just type `find -exec bar ;`, bash will treat `;` as the end of the `find` invocation, so it will only pass `-exec bar` to find.

You need to tell the shell that you mean a literal character `;`. You can do this with `\;`, also with `find -exec bar ';'`. `man find` says:

> All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of ';' is encountered.

Meaning that an argument `;` must follow the command of `-exec`.

Comment: Read the conversation with other answer. « Escaping newline » would mean the newline is not interpreted by the shell but simply given to the command. This is not the case: the newline is suppressed when prefixed by a \. Type `echo a\<newline>b` the result is `ab` not `a<newline>b`. Then `<newline>` is not escaped.

Comment: It is obvious what is meant in the answer.